# jenkins List of flow heads unset for CpsFlowExecution perhaps due to broken storage warning

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting this warning in Jenkins logs on start.

```
Feb 25, 2017 9:32:40 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
--> setting agent port for jnlp
--> setting agent port for jnlp... done
Feb 25, 2017 9:32:58 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution getCurrentHeads
WARNING: List of flow heads unset for CpsFlowExecution[null], perhaps due to broken storage
Feb 25, 2017 9:32:58 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution getCurrentHeads
WARNING: List of flow heads unset for CpsFlowExecution[null], perhaps due to broken storage
Feb 25, 2017 9:48:02 PM jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing run
INFO: bible-server #20170225.214800 branch indexing action completed: SUCCESS in 2.4 sec
```

workflow-cps, which seems to be the problem, is part of the famous pipeline plugin - which I am using.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

It doesnt seem to be having any other unwanted side effects other than this annoying warning in the logs.

Anyone got ideas how to fix this up?

Comment: Just so you know "it's not just you", I just noticed this in my logs as well.  Although, I can't say for sure "when" it started, this is my first time looking at the logs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seeing the same things.  Looking at the source code for the plugin, it appears this is related to a run of a pipeline that completes abnormally.

In my case, I had a run of a pipeline that ran all the way through but got a Java exception trying to send mail because the VM lost network connectivity. Once I deleted that failed run (not the pipeline itself), I stopped seeing those warnings in the logs.

Comment: How can we find out which pipeline? Or can it even be a 'good' pipeline which just failed during a run?